# Column footer band takes up height although not printed

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a column footer band which only displays on the last page of my report. Everything works fine except that when it is not printed, the band still takes up the space as if it were still there. How do I prevent this?
The height of the band is manditory and split type doesn't change anything.

```
<columnFooter>
    <band height="250" splitType="Prevent">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")))]]></printWhenExpression>
<!-- the elements -->
</columnFooter>
```

[image]

Comment: What about using "Print when expression"?

Comment: I used the expression and it doesnt print the content of the band but the band still takes up the height defined.

Comment: You can hide the whole band with condition

Comment: Take a look at the source code I added. The printWhenExpression is there

Comment: The column footer is always drawn even if it is hidden. You can check this document: [Report Structure in Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/report-structure-jaspersoft-studio). You can try to use Group Footer as alternate

Comment: I tried it with the group footer and it works BUT when the detail band takes up the space for the whole page the group footer gets printed on the next page with the column header band again. This looks stupid because there is no data displayed for the columns. How can I avoid this?

Comment: The Groups bands have many additional settings. You can try this options.